# Docker-Compose with Traefik "@file" in label

Tags: syntax, docker-compose, label, traefik

This might be a stupid question, but I wasn't able to find any relations in any docs.
When using traefik as revers-proxy for Docker container, I have seen many configuration examples and at some of them there is a command/syntax I don't really understand.

For example, in the labels section of a docker-compose.yml file is a label like:

```
- com.example.key=value@file
```

What does this `@file` do or mean? Is this specific for docker-compose or for traefik?

Comment: What is the `traefik` configuration ? What is the actual real key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That says which provider to use to read Traefik configuration, see example here: https://www.smarthomebeginner.com/traefik-2-docker-tutorial/